# Getting a reference to NgMap inside Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

This syntax taken from ngMap https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps works fine:

```
    angular
    .module('trails')
    .controller('MyController', function (NgMap) {
        NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
            console.log(map.getCenter());
            console.log('markers', map.markers);
            console.log('shapes', map.shapes);
        });
    });
```

But the syntax I use for declaring controllers is different and I get the error:

> angular.js:13642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMap' of undefined

It fails on the line as further below:

> NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {

The controller is declared as:

```
    angular
    .module('trails')
    .controller('ActivityDetailsController', [
        '$mdSidenav', '$mdBottomSheet', '$timeout', '$log', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams',
        ActivityDetailsController
    ]);
function ActivityDetailsController($mdSidenav, $mdBottomSheet, $timeout, $log, $http, $location, $routeParams, NgMap) {
    var self = this;

    $http.get('/activity/detailStats/' + $routeParams.id, {
        params: { max: "1000" }
    })
        .success(function (data) {
            self.stats = data.stats;

            // Zoom to fit
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < self.stats.activityTrackPoints.length; i++) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(self.stats.activityTrackPoints[i][0], self.stats.activityTrackPoints[i][1]);
                bounds.extend(latlng);
            }
            NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });

        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.error('https error', status, data);
        })
        .finally(function () {
        });
```

I have tried adding the NgMap in other obvious places, such as:

```
...'$routeParams', NgMap,
        ActivityDetailsController...
```

or doing a ActivityDetailsController.$inject = NgMap before the controller declaration etc but it gives a similar error to above in that NgMap cannot be referenced.

Edit: ngMap dependency was setup in another file similar to the answers already. Sorry I didn't put this earlier, but the above code that works and doesn't work are in the same place together so I thought it seemed ok to leave that out originally.

```
var app = angular
.module('trails', ['ngMaterial', 'md.data.table', 'ngRoute', 'ngMap'])
```

I'm not sure if this is to do with the way I am incorrectly trying to inject NgMap using this controller declaration or something in NgMap...or most likely my inexperience with either framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app= angular.module('trails', ['ngMap']);
  app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $interval, NgMap) {
    var vm = this;
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
      vm.map = map;
    });
});
```

Comment: No luck on referencing vm.map or in my case self.map.  The error is still "Cannot read property 'getMap' of undefined" , so it looks like the NgMap is not "injecting" in this way of declaring the controller function.

Comment: .controller('ActivityDetailsController', [
        '$mdSidenav', '$mdBottomSheet', '$timeout', '$log', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams','NgMap',
        ActivityDetailsController
    ])

Comment: You got it Abcd, quotes around the 'NgMap' are needed here as well (I tried without always), love your work!  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `ngMap` dependency.

Declare your module this way:

```
angular.module('trails', ['ngMap'])
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually already had that since one way works and the other doesn't. I updated the question to include this now so it's more obvious. Cheers.